# Exo player taking too much time to start to play audio sometimes in android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using exo player to play audio from remote url.here is my code

```
var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri);
            var userAgent = Util.GetUserAgent(_context, "ExoPlayerDemo");
            var defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
            var defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(_context, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
            var extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, defaultDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
            var defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            var adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
            var defaultTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

            if (_player != null)
            {
                _player.PlayWhenReady = false;
                _player.Release();
                player = null;
            }
            DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().SetBufferDurationsMs(32 * 1024, 64 * 1024, 1024, 1024).CreateDefaultLoadControl();
            _player = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(_context, defaultTrackSelector, loadControl);
            _player.AddListener(new PlayerEventListener());
            _player.Prepare(extractorMediaSource);
            _player.PlayWhenReady = true;
```

Initially audios started to play within 6 sec using this exo player code in xamarin android but sometimes few mp3 file load is too mush slow,its taking around 25 seconds to start to play.

How to solve this problem.Also Exo player have any play progress so that I can show the progress on slider?

Comment: ExoPlayer supports high-performance features like DASH and HLS streaming that are not available in MediaPlayer. Please check your Stream type. Or you could try to use MediaPlayer.

Comment: I already used MediaPlayer,but it will take a lot of time to play audio.Thats why I choose Exo player.